# Обращение к имени переменной

Tags: javascript, react-native

Добрый день. 
Вопрос: пусть есть `let foo = 123;` и `let bar = 'foo';` 
Как из bar обратиться к содержимому foo?

В частности, чтобы в React Native уметь делать вот так:

`return ( <this.props.currentScreen />  );`

когда в this.props.currentScreen лежит строка с именем компонента.

Comment: `let obj = {}; obj.foo = 123; let bar = 'foo'; console.log(obj[bar]) /* 123 */`

Comment: Спасибо, это помогает. Только вместо <obj[bar] /> необходимо React.createElement(obj[bar], null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как из bar обратиться к содержимому foo?

Что это значит? `bar` это строка, `foo` - число.

> В частности, чтобы в React Native уметь делать вот так:
>
> `return ( <this.props.currentScreen />  );`

Вот так пробовали?

```
const { currentScreen } = this.props;
return (
  <div>
    { currentScreen }
  <div/>
);
```

**UPDATE 1**

Попробуйте этот вариант:

```
import someComponent from './components/someComponent';
import anotherComponent from './components/anotherComponent';

const map = {
  someComponent: someComponent,
  anotherComponent: anotherComponent,
}
const Component = map[this.props.currentScreen];
const props = this.props.currentScreenProps;

return <Component ...props />
```

**UPDATE 2**

Рабочий пример:

```js
class someComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        someComponent! {this.props.text}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class anotherComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        anotherComponent! {this.props.text}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  render() {
    const map = {
      someComponent: someComponent,
      anotherComponent: anotherComponent,
    }
    const Component = map[this.props.currentScreen];
    const props = this.props.currentScreenProps;
    if (!Component) return null;

    return (
      <Component {...props} />
    );
  }
}

// const currentScreen = 'someComponent';
const currentScreen = 'anotherComponent';
const props = { text: 'Hello World'};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App currentScreen={currentScreen} currentScreenProps={props} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Дело в том, что после 
```
const { currentScreen } = this.props;
return (
  <div>
    { currentScreen }
  <div/>
);
```
будет див со строкой, а мне нужен экземпляр класса с названием, которое в этой строке хранится.

Ответ в комментарии к вопросу в целом решает мою проблему, только в этом случае нельзя использовать JSX-синтаксис.

Comment: Так уже понятнее! Обновил ответ.

Comment: Добавил пример ниже

Comment: Да, вариант со словарем работает, спору нет. Единственный минус - от не учитывает того факта, что имена классов заведомо совпадают с возможными значениями в props:

`const map = {
  someComponent: someComponent,
  anotherComponent: anotherComponent,
}` 

В этом месте есть очевидное дублирование. Компоненты уже подключены в начале файла, а мы их все руками в словарь забиваем.

Это не к вопросу о правильности ответа, это общее концептуальное замечание.

Comment: А как вы иначе от импортов избавитесь и узнаете, какой компонент включать? Как вариант, передавать уже сам компонент через пропсы, так тоже можно.

Comment: От импортов-то никуда не деться, это понятно. Была мысль, что _может быть_ есть некий хак, который после импортов вместо создания словаря позволил бы сразу обращаться к компонентам типа `<[[scope]][this.props.currentScreen] />`

Comment: Вообще ваш вопрос похож на "как сделать свой роутер для React-Native?". Может, есть уже такое для React-Native? Я использовал **react-router-redux**, в его случае можно все компоненты импортировать в одном месте, а в роутере передавать эти компоненты как пропсы уже. Так количество повторений сведено к минимуму, и словарь не нужен.